# Can I 'destroy' created class?

Tags: c#, class, garbage-collection

I've a *System.Windows.Forms* application with one additional class. This class will be called **many times from different objects** to make them some minor changes.

I'm using this code to call the class, which creates new one for every object(sender):

```
Component component = new Component();
```

Later i dispose every object. And my question is - **When i dispose an object, which has created a component class before, will that class also be deleted/disposed immediately from the RAM memory, or i should wait for the Garbage Collector to clean it later?**

Comment: Class cannot be deleted, only objects are deleted. Garbage collector will do it, if you not disposed the object

Comment: GC will remove everything from memory that has no future use in the program.

Comment: Even if you dispose a object explicitly the GC is non deterministic, so you can't gaurantee that it will be released from memory straight away

Comment: GC only runs when needed, but you can explicitly invoke GC using code

Comment: Benefit of "managed programming languages" (which C# is) that you don't need to dispose every object by yourself. GarbageCollector will do the job

Comment: @Fabio haha GC isn't a benefit, it is a hack due to how bad we are at memory management!

Comment: @Sherlock you can, but you shouldn't invoke GarbageCollector explicitly

Comment: @Fabio yes because program will have a performance issue due to stoppage of currently executed threads

Comment: Only worry about this if you start to run into memory problems. My guess is that you won't.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not immediately be removed from memory.
As long as there are no references to it (there shouldn't be if the object is scoped to the `Form`) then the GC will remove it at its pleasure after the `Form` has been disposed.